# SSMS change Select shortcut to SELECT *

Tags: sql, select, ssms, ssms-2012

I've already changed the right-click shortcut from `SELECT TOP 1000` to `Select All`, but when it executes the query, it lists out all columns in the query instead of just running `SELECT *`.  Nitpicking here, but it's an extra step when I add a new column and can't just refresh the `Select All` query that's already up.

Is there any way to make it just `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT [col1], [col2], ...`?

Comment: write and save a select * query.

Comment: @DanBracuk I was hoping I could change the context menu shortcut, but oh well. If that's what it takes, it's probably easier to just do the default Select All and manually change it to a * each time...